# Не выполняется третье условие else if

Tags: javascript, if

Не выполняется третье условие else if. Первые два работают корректно. В чем причина?

```php
if (arr[0] == 2) {
  certificate.html('<a href="#level-other" class="js-fancybox">Сертификация IPMA Вам не подходит.  Скорее всего, Вам подойдет сертификация <b class="js-email-level">PMI - PMP или CAPM.</b></a>');
} else if (arr[0] == 1 || arr[3] == 1 && arr[3] == 2 || arr[4] == 2 || arr[5] == 1 && arr[5] == 2) {
  certificate.html('Вам подходит IPMA <a href="#level-d" class="js-fancybox"><b class="js-email-level">уровень D "Менеджер проекта"</b></a>');
} else if (arr[0] == 1 || arr[2] == 4 || arr[3] == 3 || arr[4] == 1 || arr[5] == 3 || arr[6] == 1 && arr[6] == 2 && arr[6] == 3) {
  certificate.html('Вам подходит IPMA <a href="#level-c" class="js-fancybox"><b class="js-email-level">уровень C "Руководитель проекта"</b></a>');
}
```

Comment: Опишите исходную задачу. При каких условиях, что должно выполняться. Потому, что в коде дичайшая мешанина условий.

Answer (score 0):

Причина в конце:

```
... && arr[6] == 2 && arr[6] == 3) ...
```

Не может один и тот же элемент одновременно быть равным и 2 и 3.

Comment: даже если оставляю один вариант arr[6] == 1, все равно условие не выполняется.

Comment: @lglmns Так у Вас и во втором условии фигня записана `arr[3] == 1 && arr[3] == 2`

Comment: Автор, сделай форматирование кода и отступы, чтобы ты сам понимал, что у тебя за условия делаются. И все увидишь, ей богу